# Is there an ISO or similar recognized standard for Icons?

Tags: icon, web-standards

I had this question popping out while viewing some ISO standards such as ISO 9142.

I searched a little but couldn't find an explicit ISO standard that is specifically for Computer Icons.

So, has one such standard been published? or a similar recognized one?.

Comment: It would be nice to leverage others' learned recognition in my diagrams rather than searching for obscure clipart each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ISO's technical committee [TC 145](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/list_of_iso_technical_committees/iso_technical_committee.htm?commid=52662) is responsible for *graphical symbols*:

> Standardization in the field of graphical symbols as well as of colours and shapes, whenever these elements form part of the message that a symbol is intended to convey, e.g. a safety sign.

You can find a list of [related](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=52662&published=on&includesc=true) ISO standards and those [under their direct responsibility](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=52662&published=on).

---

If the icons contain text, have a look at W3C's [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/), where you can find guidelines how to make the images accessible (contrast).

Comment: You can browse them at https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#home and tick 'Graphical symbols'. You have to enter a search term, but if you just want to browse by category, terms like 'for' and 'to' match most of them...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an ISO rule for icons, but there definitely are some 'standards' for Desktop applications.

Size-wise, Windows .ico icons range from 16x16 to 48x48 (pre-Vista), up to 256x256 (post-Vista). Mac OS X .icns icons go from 16x16 up to 512x512. Favicons for web have to be 16x16.

There are some naming agreements as well, they have to be composed of US-ASCII characters, and the dash “-” is used to separate levels of specificity (edit-copy, edit-cut, edit-paste).

But I think every program has its own conventions. For example, [Symantec follows this one](https://sort.symantec.com/public/documents/sf/5.0MP3/solaris/html/vcs_users/ch_admin_vcs_from_mcm10.html). While some of them are more or less common ground ("Color icons indicate objects that are in a healthy, running condition. Gray icons indicate objects that are offline."), specific functionalities follow their own internal rules.

Comment: Depending on the platform for which the icons are to be used are the standards or guidelines that one should follow right?.

Comment: @UriHerrera Yes, most likely. What are you designing for?

Comment: Well, actually it's for my own OS project for which I'm doing the Guidelines but I wondered if besides those if there was an International standard in place.

Comment: Not that I know of. I just came across these [open icon packages](http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/downloads.html), if you don't have your icons already they might be of help.

Comment: Actually I've finished [them](http://fav.me/d4utllr) but sort of like wanted to have them certified just as the rest of the UI this OS will end up using because as I understand for UIs there are various standards currently published.

Comment: They look amazing! As I said there is no ISO **as far as I'm concerned**, but keep the question open because other people might have new information.